# How can I add values to an empty SELECT?

Tags: javascript, html

I know change the value of an INPUT TEXT.

```
<script>
    document.write('<input type="text" id="1" value="Hello">');
    document.getElementById('1').value = ("Good bye");
</script>
```

How can I add values ​​to an empty SELECT with this method?

```
<script>
    document.write('<select><option id="2"></option><option id="3"></option></select>');
    document.getElementById ........;
</script>
```

I want my empty SELECT becomes a SELECT with two options: "Hello" and "Good bye."

Comment: Do you already have a select element? Is that what you are saying?

Answer (score 1):

Why not write:

```
document.write('<select><option id="2">Hello</option><option id="3">Good bye</option></select>');
```

Or if you want to add one programmatically:

```
document.write('<select id="s"></select>');
var s = document.getElementById("s");

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Hello";
s.add(option);

var option = document.createElement("option");
option.text = "Good bye";
s.add(option);
```

Comment: I think it is better to use `appendChild` instead of `add`

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple ....

```
<script>
    var add = function(){
    var sel = document.getElementById("sel");
    var in1 = document.getElementById("in").value;

    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.innerHTML = in1;

    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
</script>
<select id="sel">

</select>
<input id="in" type="text" />
<button onclick="add();">add</button>
```

here is the demo: [CLICK](http://jsfiddle.net/ay2nF/) 
another exanple how to do this thing by using `innerHTML` is here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Phcg2/)

this is done by making a element as you know `option` by using javascript and then it is appended in the element `select` and the option text is the value of input box... and hope you are understood.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it easily with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select").append('<option id="3" value="somevalue">Some text</option>"');
});
```